# How do I correctly get the largest and smallest numbers in a sequence of numbers?

Tags: java, math

I'm supposed to get the smallest and largest number out of a sequence of numbers. I know my method body for each method is probably not right. Any help?

```
public class DataSet
{
  private int sum;
  private int count;
  private int largest;
  private int smallest;

  public DataSet()
   {
   sum = 0;
   count = 0;
   largest = 0;
   smallest = 0;
   }

 public void addValue(int x)
  {
   sum = sum + x;
   count++;
  }

 public int getSum()
 {
   return sum;
 }

 public double getAverage()
 {
   double average = sum/count;
   return average;
 }

 public int getLargest()
 {
   int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//not giving right answer, don't know how to use
   return largest;
 }

  public int getSmallest()
 {
   int smallest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;//not giving right answer, don't know how to use
   return smallest;
  }
}
```

---

Here is the tester class if it is needed, although I don't think the problem lies here.

```
 public class DataSetTester
 {  
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    DataSet myData = new DataSet();
    myData.addValue(100);
    myData.addValue(5);
    myData.addValue(4);
    myData.addValue(2);

    System.out.println("Sum = " + myData.getSum());
    System.out.println("Average = " + myData.getAverage());
    System.out.println("Largest value = " + myData.getLargest());
    System.out.println("Smallest value = " + myData.getSmallest());
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` returns the largest and smallest number that is representable by an `Integer` value

Instead, in you add method, you need to be comparing the values as they are added, you can use [`Math.min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) and [`Math.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) to make the comparison easier, for example...

```
private int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

public void addValue(int x)
{
    smallest = Math.min(smallest, x);
    largest = Math.max(largest, x);
    sum = sum + x;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather easy task that you may just be thinking too hard about. When you add a value, you have to check if is the smallest or largest value by adding some if statements to addValue().

```
    public void addValue(int x)
    {
        sum = sum + x;
        count++;
        if(x > largest)
             largest = x;
        else if(x < smallest)
             smallest = x;
    }
```

After that, you would just have to return the largest and smallest in your getSmallest and getLargest method. They should look like this:

```
    public int getLargest()
   {
   return largest;
   }

   public int getSmallest()
   {
   return smallest;
   }
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use an if statement for this.

Comment: @Derv please put this comment in question and mark MadProgrammer's answer as accepted one :D

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One simple solution is to modify your `addValue()` method:

```
private int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

public void addValue(int x) {
   sum = sum + x;
   count++;
   this.largest = (x > this.largest) ? x : this.largest;
   this.smallest = (x < this.smallest) ? x : this.smallest;
}
```

Also, you will need to remove the lines:

```
int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

and

```
int smallest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

from the getters.